# Asp.net C# identity 3 capas - reemplazo de session en VS 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, mvc

Consulta, antiguamente cuando programaba en asp.net form lo hacia con sessiones, ahora que estoy trabajando con asp.net mvc 5 en n capas, como puedo obtener por ejemplo el ID o Nombre completo del usuario logueado desde cualquier parte de la aplicacion?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que usas Identity para realizar el login de tu aplicación por lo que para acceder al nombre o id del usuario que ha iniciado sesión tienes que usar:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId()
User.Identity.GetUserName()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente he visto que Identity cuenta con opciones que se parece a sesiones, como es el Claims based.

Comment: Si te ha servido marcarlo como respuesta por si le sirve a alguien más.

Answer (score 0):

Usted puede aplicar datos en una sesión utilizando **HttpContext**. Sin embargo, debe tener cuidado con tales implementaciones, el controlador de vista de modelo no tiene estado. La sesión, sin embargo, dictará alguna forma de estado.

Tendrá que dar cuenta de eso, de lo contrario, podría introducir una gran cantidad de variables de sesión huérfanas si no se contabilizan. Lo cual podría consumir memoria en su entorno rápidamente dependiendo de su aplicación.

Si la aplicación es pequeña, puede hacerlo fácilmente con lo siguiente en su Controlador:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add ("Título", "Datos");
```